# Ant : Output for Execution of SQL file using apply task in ant

Tags: sql, ant

I am a new bee to Ant and would love to hear a positive response and solution for my quesion. While using osql, executing of sql files and the output can be saved if we follow the format **osql -S SERVERNAME -U username -P password -d database -i sample.sql -o c:\output\results.csv**. Likewise, how can i achieve this in ant using apply task. I googled it out that i can run a bunch of files using this but can i also get the result file for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Example

```
├── build.xml
└── src
    ├── sample1.sql
    ├── sample2.sql
    ├── sample3.sql
    ├── sample4.sql
    └── sample5.sql
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

   <target name="run">
      <mkdir dir="output"/>

      <apply executable="osql">
         <arg line="-S SERVERNAME -U username -P password -d database -i"/>
         <srcfile/>
         <arg line="-o"/>
         <targetfile/>
         <fileset dir="src" includes="*.sql"/>
         <globmapper from="*.sql" to="output/*.csv"/>
      </apply>
   </target>

   <target name="clean">
      <delete dir="output"/>
   </target>

</project>
```

Comment: thanks Mark. By making the changes as said above, i am able to run the scripts, but the results are saved in different file names same as the src sql file. I would like to add the results should be a consolidated one.